# Nagios Configuration Error

Tags: nagios

Running `/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg`
Does not give any error. The output is Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check

However when i try to do some configurations thru the xi interface, the configuration verification fails.

```
Configuration submitted for processing...
Waiting for configuration verification.......
Configuration verification failed.
```

Nagios is till able to monitor my services and hosts but i cant do any changes to the configuration using xi interface.

I took a look at the configuration Snapshots and saw that there was 40 over errors. I am very puzzled as to why it doesn't show when i run the sanity check (plus it is able to monitor those hosts that produced the error). Another thing to note : i am able to restart nagios. - doesn't this prove that there isnt any error?  thus it could restart normally?

Comment: http://support.nagios.com/wiki/index.php/Nagios_XI:FAQs#Apply_Configuration_Fails.2C_No_Configuration_Problems

Apply Configuration Fails, No Configuration Problems

Answer (score 1):

Try tuning your service timeout in your nagios.cfg, usually when I have large configs I get this error as a result of timeouts. I've had success bumping the default 60 (in R1.6) to 300.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely causes are that

- xi is not using /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg as its initial config file
- there is a permissions issue which allows you to read the the files from the command line, but which are not readable by the uid invoked via xi